# Update a table through another table in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, updating

I want to update Table1 based on updated information that I have stored in Table2.  Where the Table1.User = Table2.User, I want to Update Table1.account to be the value of Table2.account
I tried two different SQL queries in Access:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.account = Table2.account
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.User = Table2.User
WHERE Table1.User = Table2.User
;
```

This one gave me a syntax error, saying that it was missing an operator

```
UPDATE Table1
SET account = (SELECT account
FROM Table2
WHERE Table1.User = Table2.User);
```

And this one gave said that the 'Operation must use an updateable query'

I have been working with Access and SQL for not very long, so any suggestions or insights into where I went wrong are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

MS Access uses a bit different syntax to SQL Server. In your case you need to write:

```
UPDATE Table1
 INNER JOIN Table2
             ON Table1.User = Table2.User
SET Table1.account = Table2.account;
```